# What are the most common Java Script functions used in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am familiar with javascriptExecutor function which is used in Selenium WebDriver, such as how to click on an element, scroll down, and navigate the page. I would like to know if there are other functionalities of JS to implement in Selenium?

Comment: what do you mean, "to implement in selenium"? What's the goal here? if you want the documentation, you should read the documentation: https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. There are occasions that we cannot perform clicking on a button in Selenium, so we use JS method here. What other JS methods are commonly used in Selenium?

Comment: I see a lot of people using javascript to click things, but this should be avoided. (IMHO)  The whole point of using Selenium is to simulate the end user, and the end user does not use javascript to click a button.  (The exceptions you see are there for a reason and should not be worked around in this way...)  The cases where I think it's useful is to generate HTML5 click and drag events, or to open a new tab/window.  (Though I assume those functionalities will be supported by all webdrivers in the future...)

Comment: @pcalkins Completely agree with you. _HTML5 click and drag_ in its basic form still works but doesn't works when with Angular elements when `draggable=true`

Comment: @pcalkins You are right. Thank you for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can also get element text**

```
 private String jsGetElementText(String cssSelector) {
            JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            return (String) javascriptExecutor.executeScript(String.format(
                    "var element = document.querySelector(\"%s\");\n" +
                            "if(element != null){\n" +
                            "    return element.innerHTML;\n" +
                            "}else{\n" +
                            "    return \"\";\n" +
                            "}", cssSelector));
        }
```

**Drag and Drop file**

```
    public void dropFile(File filePath, WebElement target, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
        if (!filePath.exists())
            throw new WebDriverException("File not found: " + filePath.toString());

        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        String JS_DROP_FILE =
                "var target = arguments[0]," +
                        "    offsetX = arguments[1]," +
                        "    offsetY = arguments[2]," +
                        "    document = target.ownerDocument || document," +
                        "    window = document.defaultView || window;" +
                        "" +
                        "var input = document.createElement('INPUT');" +
                        "input.type = 'file';" +
                        "input.style.display = 'none';" +
                        "input.onchange = function () {" +
                        "  var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect()," +
                        "      x = rect.left + (offsetX || (rect.width >> 1))," +
                        "      y = rect.top + (offsetY || (rect.height >> 1))," +
                        "      dataTransfer = { files: this.files };" +
                        "" +
                        "  ['dragenter', 'dragover', 'drop'].forEach(function (name) {" +
                        "    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');" +
                        "    evt.initMouseEvent(name, !0, !0, window, 0, 0, 0, x, y, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null);" +
                        "    evt.dataTransfer = dataTransfer;" +
                        "    target.dispatchEvent(evt);" +
                        "  });" +
                        "" +
                        "  setTimeout(function () { document.body.removeChild(input); }, 25);" +
                        "};" +
                        "document.body.appendChild(input);" +
                        "return input;";

        WebElement input = (WebElement) jse.executeScript(JS_DROP_FILE, target, offsetX, offsetY);
        input.sendKeys(filePath.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
        waitFor(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(input));
    }
```

**change opacity for field**

```
    public void changeOpacityForUploadField() {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"input[id*='upload']\").style.opacity='1'");
    }
```

**Stop page loading**

```
public void stopPageLoading() {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("return window.stop");
    }
```

**open browser extension**

```
public void openBrowserExtension(){
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.postMessage('clicked_browser_action', '*')");
}
```

**wait for page load**

```
public void waitForPageLoad(){
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        waitForCondition().until(d->js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
    }
```

Comment: Good answer as per the question which is a bit broad as per stackoverflow standards. However the functions are overkill but are used in the rarest of rare (exceptional) cases.

Comment: @DebanjanB These functions are often used in Selenium which is very useful. I have not used these JS functions you already shared. Thank you.